# Open google maps on Dialog crashes at the second click

Tags: android, google-maps, dialog

I'm develop app with save the location of enter and exit places.
and the map open in a Dialog .
every things work fine at the first time im click to open the dialog and see the location, but when i click back button or close (dialMap.dismiss();) and try to click again to open the dialog i'ts crash!
here my code:

```
public void openMap(double lat,double lng,double lat2,double lng2) throws IOException{

            final Dialog dialMap = new Dialog(this);
        dialMap.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialMap.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_map);
        Button btnExit = (Button) dialMap.findViewById(R.id.dialog_map_close);
        if(map==null){
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title("Enter"));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat2, lng2)).title("Exit"));
}
        dialMap.show();

        btnExit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialMap.dismiss();          

            }
        });

    }
```

logcat error:

```
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.app.Dialog.setContentView(Dialog.java:478)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at com.bibas.workclock.ListOfHours.openMap(ListOfHours.java:3741)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at com.bibas.workclock.ListOfHours$20.onClick(ListOfHours.java:2571)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f060082, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4971)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
05-19 16:23:39.936: E/AndroidRuntime(11365):    ... 19 more
```

what i need to to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logcat - it would appear that there are issues in your binary

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f060082, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
```

Logcat is saying that you have 2 id's with the same name?

Also what is on line 92

```
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

and Line 137?

```
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
```

Comment: So? what i need to do?

Comment: Each fragment should have it's own ID in your XML file. That is all I can see the issue could be, as everything else should work fine